# While loop looping through data twice

Tags: php, html, ajax, while-loop

So I have this code, and I've been fretting over it for several hours now and my friend and I can't find the solution. It display reviews based on a descending ID pulled from a database. This is an endless scroll type of script to eliminate pagination. For some reason when I hit the bottom of the page and run the script, the while loop is iterating through the data twice. So if its supposed to display reviews ID 5 - 10, it display 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5; instead of 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5. This is going to be a very large bit of code, But I hope you can help me with my problem. 
Thanks in advance!!

```
<?php 
include("../mysql_server/connect_to_mysql.php");


if($_GET['lastPost']) {
$mysqlQuery = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `reviews` WHERE `review_id` < "' . $_GET['lastPost'] . '" ORDER BY `review_id` DESC LIMIT 0, 10');

while ($review_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysqlQuery)) {

    $review_title = $review_row['review_title'];
    $user_id = $review_row['user_id'];
    $user_firstname = $review_row['user_firstname'];
    $user_lastname = $review_row['user_lastname'];
    $review_id = $review_row['review_id'];
    $review_body = $review_row['review_body'];
    $review_referral = $review_row['review_referral'];

        // Code to append text for title
        // strip tags to avoid breaking any html
        $review_title = strip_tags($review_title);

        if (strlen($review_title) > 30) {

            // truncate string
            $stringCut = substr($review_title, 0, 30);

            // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
            $review_title = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'...'; 
        }
        // Code to append text and add Read More
        // strip tags to avoid breaking any html
        $review_body = strip_tags($review_body);

        if (strlen($review_body) > 230) {

            // truncate string
            $stringCut = substr($review_body, 0, 230);

            // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
            $review_body = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a class="reviewContentLink" href="../../pages/home_page/post_content.php?id='. $review_id .'">See Full Post</a>'; 
        } else {
            $review_body .= '<a class="reviewContentLink" href="../../pages/home_page/post_content.php?id='. $review_id .'">See Full Post</a>';
        }

    $review_date = $review_row['review_date'];
        $review_date = date_create($review_date);
        $review_date = date_format($review_date, 'g:ia \o\n F jS\, Y');
    $user_firstname = $review_row['user_firstname'];
    $review_rating = $review_row['rating'];



    ///////  Mechanism to Display Pic. See if they have uploaded a pic or not  //////////////////////////
    $check_pic = "../members/$user_id/thumb_image01.jpg";
    $default_pic = "../members/0/image01.jpg";
        if (file_exists($check_pic)) {
            $review_pic = "<img src=\"../$check_pic\" width=\"80px\" />"; 
        } else {
            $review_pic = "<img src=\"../$default_pic\" width=\"80px\" />"; 
        }





    include_once('../include/star_display.php');            




    //Pull the Review Category from the row
    $review_category = "";
    $review_category = $review_row['review_category'];
    include_once('../include/review_category.php');


    //Pull the Referral Category from the row
    $referral_category = $review_row['referral_category'];
    include_once('../include/referral_category.php');


    //Code for URL for Each Review
    $review_url = $review_row['review_url'];
    if (!function_exists('remove_http')) {
        function remove_http($url = '') {
            return(str_replace(array('http://','https://'), '', $url));
        }
    }
   //CODE TO DISTINGUISH REFERRALS FROM REVIEWS         
        //Final Output List
        if($review_referral == 0) {
                //Code for Displaying URL Link
                $review_url = remove_http($review_url);
                $review_url = "<a target='_BLANK' href='http://". $review_url ."'>Buy It Here!</a> ";

                    echo ''. $review_id .' '. $review_referral .'
                    <div class="display_newsfeed" id="'.$review_id.'">
                        <table id="'.$review_id.'" style="width:98.5%; border:#00B347 1px solid; margin:10px 0px 20px 10px;">
                        <td style="float:left; width:15%; border-right:1px solid #DDDDDD; margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
                                            <div class="review_user_name"><a href="../../pages/profile_page/profile_page.php?id='. $user_id .'">'. $user_firstname.' '. $user_lastname .'</a></div>
                                            <div class="review_prof_pic"><a href="../../pages/profile_page/profile_page.php?id='. $user_id .'">'. $review_pic .'</a></div>
                                            <div class="bought_it_newsfeed">Bought It!</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="float:right; width:82%;">
                                        <div class="review_title_p">
                                            <p><span class="review_title">'. $review_title .'</span><span class="review_date_p">'. $review_date .'</span><span class="review_stars">'. $review_stars .'</span></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="review_read_more">
                                            <p class="review_body_p">'. $review_body .'</p><br />
                                            <div>
                                                <div style="float:left;" class="review_black_font_link">Website:'.$review_url.'</div>
                                                <div style="float:right; margin-right:20px;" class="review_black_font_link">Category: '.$review_category_post .'</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </td>

                        </table>
                        <hr style="margin:0px 20px 0px 20px;" />    
                        </div>
                                    ';

              } else if($review_referral == 1) {    
                //Code for Displaying URL Link
                $review_url = remove_http($review_url);
                $review_url = "<a target='_BLANK' href='http://". $review_url ."'>Click Here</a> ";

                echo '
                        <div class="display_newsfeed" id="'.$review_id.'">
                        <table id="'.$review_id.'" style="width:98.5%; border:#0099FF 1px solid; margin:10px 0px 20px 10px;">
                        <td style="float:left; width:15%; border-right:1px solid #DDDDDD; margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;">
                                            <div class="review_user_name"><a href="../../pages/profile_page/profile_page.php?id='. $user_id .'">'. $user_firstname.' '. $user_lastname .'</a></div>
                                            <div class="review_prof_pic"><a href="../../pages/profile_page/profile_page.php?id='. $user_id .'">'. $review_pic .'</a></div>
                                            <div class="referral_newsfeed">Referral</div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="float:right; width:82%;">
                                        <div class="review_title_p">
                                            <p><a href="../../pages/home_page/post_content.php?id='. $review_id .'">'. $review_title .'</a><span class="review_date_p">'. $review_date .'</span><span class="review_stars">'. $review_stars .'</span></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="review_read_more">
                                            <p class="review_body_p">'. $review_body .'</p><br />
                                            <div>
                                                <div style="float:left;" class="review_black_font_link">Business Website:'. $review_url .'</div>
                                                <div style="float:right; margin-right:20px;" class="review_black_font_link">Category: '. $referral_category_post .'</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </td>

                        </table>
                        <hr style="margin:0px 20px 0px 20px;" />    
                        </div>
                                    ';
                }
}             

} else {
 echo "didn't work";
}

?>
```

Comment: If it is looping twice, it's likely the script is actually running twice, and it may be because of a rewrite rule.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you give me an example of a rewrite rule?

Comment: If you don't know what it is, surely it is not the problem.

Comment: if your web server is setup to redirect the request, and does so improperly, it may result in two calls to the script.  Read your web server logs. Do you see two lines for every call to this script?

Comment: @user1371489 Rewrite rules are generally found in `.htaccess` and instruct browsers to go to a different URL than what they originally sent.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also sure there is no corruption in your database? you can try just

```
while ($review_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysqlQuery)) {
 echo $review_row['review_title'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: That would just return the review title, perfectly normal, the problem is, it would return it twice. Everything runs right and displays perfectly, but it run/displays twice. So if review_title = "apple Iphone" then it would return: appleIphone <br /> appleIphone <br /> for the above code..

Comment: Of course, there are no other "echo" in the included scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code that calls/posts to this script?  As the others stated, it is quite possible this code is being called twice.

Also, if you run this query directly in the database, what is returned?

```
SELECT * 
FROM `reviews` 
WHERE `review_id` < (insert the id here) 
ORDER BY `review_id` DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```